# Dynamically redirecting in django

Tags: python, django, redirect, dynamic, response.redirect

I am trying to dynamically redirect from one dynamic page to another. Think about being on an IMDB movie page (dynamic) and then following the link to the writer/director/actor page(dynamic).

These are the urls:

```
   urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('writer/<int:id>', views.writer, name="writer"),
    path('title/<int:id>', views.title, name="title"),
    path('creator/', views.creator, name="creator"),
]
```

This is the index.html:

```
{% for pilots in pilot %}
    <div>
        <p>Title: <a href="title/{{ pilots.id }}">{{ pilots.title }}</a></p>
        {% for writers in pilots.creators.all %}
            <p>Writer: <a href="writer/{{ writers.id }}">{{ writers.writer }}</a></p>
        {% endfor %}
        
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

This is the title.html (which the dynamic ahref isn't working):

```
{% for title in titles %}
        <p>{{title.title}}</p>
        <p>{{title.count}}</p>
        <p>{{title.year}}</p>
        <p>{{title.description}}</p>
        {% for creators in title.creators.all %}
            <a href="creator/">{{creators.writer}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And this is the views.py:

```
def title(request, id):
    titles = Pilot.objects.filter(id=id)
    context = {
        'titles': titles,
    }
    return render(request, 'title.html', context)

def creator(request):
    return redirect(f'writer/{id}')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you need: [remove hardcode in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/zh-hans/3.1/intro/tutorial03/#removing-hardcoded-urls-in-templates)

your code may changed to

```
{% for title in titles %}
        <p>{{title.title}}</p>
        <p>{{title.count}}</p>
        <p>{{title.year}}</p>
        <p>{{title.description}}</p>
        {% for creators in title.creators.all %}
            <a href="{% url 'writer' creators.writer.id %}">{{creators.writer}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

and what's more, you create a `namespace`(when with multiple APP). see more from the doc.  :)

Comment: I tried what you recommended but I another error: Reverse for 'name' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['name/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$'] @tomy0608

Comment: check if you registered the app. 
it said  
> Reverse for 'name' with arguments '('',)' not found.. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['name/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$']

maybe your have registered an app with `name/(?P<id>[0-9]+)$` in it.

Comment: You're right. I didn't mean to make it more confusing, but I changed the path name from 'Writer' to 'Name' for more clarity on my part via urls.py/views.py. So if the path was still named 'writer', I would have gotten the same error. I'm wondering if it has something to do with the reserve lookup. Maybe I'm fudging that up

Comment: @T_hall be cautious with resolve name, module name, or whatever you using. try not mix them up. the better practice is using name-space . and  absolute import is a plus.

Comment: Thank you for all your help! One more question. The get_absolute_url works until I try to use it in for loop within the for-loop. When I click on the link for the author id page, it loads the title id, basically reload the same page I'm on

Comment: this is the example:  {% for title in titles %}
        <p>{{title.title}}</p>
        <p>{{title.count}}</p>
        <p>{{title.year}}</p>
        <p>{{title.description}}</p>
        {% for creators in title.creators.all %}
            <a href="{{ creators.get_absolute_url }}">{{creators.writer}}</a>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}